# Is there a way to associate a descriptive name to a MAC address in OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt

Does anyone know if there's a way to associate a descriptive name to a MAC address on OpenWRT/LEDE, without necessary being able to change the hostname of the device?

The answer is not hostname, for users who think the answer is hostname.

Currently, the DHCP table on OpenWRT/LEDE shows the name of the devices that these devices gave(or their owners gave), however, these names mean nothing to me.

For example, currently, the DHCP table shows

```
android-1boeusthaoeu <MAC address> <IP address>
? <another MAC address> <another IP address>
```

I would like to see, for example,

```
"jim's device" <MAC address> <IP address>
"The TV" <another MAC address> <another IP address>
```

Is there a package, or something I can configure to make it so?

Comment: There appears to be a confusion between hostname set on a client device and hostnames set on a router - the latter appeats to be what's being asked and is the answer to this question. On router OSes, `hostname` is set by configuring a static IP for the MAC entry, which is set either via LuCI's _Network_ → _DHCP and DNS_ → _Static Leases_ or via [`/etc/config/dhcp`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp) _(see [Static leases](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp#static_leases))_. Within hostnames, whitespaces and symbols cannot be used, but hyphens can be

Comment: There is no confusion, at least for me. There's literally no way to set hostnames on weighing machines, certain TVs, certain family appliances, etc... Note my question says "descriptive name", and I also said "not hostname". It appears most people who answers have difficulty with understanding what "not hostname" is, because their answers are "hostname"-centric answers.

Comment: **Hostnames set on a client** _(e.g. weighing machines, certain TVs, appliances, etc.)_ **is _not_ the same thing as the _network_ hostname set on a router via a _Static Lease_.** Network _Static Lease_ hostnames have _nothing_ whatsoever to do with a client device's OS hostname - one is a hostname for a machine set via a client device's OS, whereas the other is a _network_ hostname configured on a router via a _Static Lease_ - **neither of these has anything at all to do with the other** _(it's simpler when the network hostname matches the machine's hostname, but it's not required)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Configuring a Static Lease for the MAC entry on a router/managed switch is the standard way of doing what's being asked. This also makes accessing client devices over a network simpler since their `<NetworkHostname>.<localdomain>` can be used instead of their IP to access the device _(`LocalDomain` is always set on the router (OpenWrt LuCI: Network → DHCP and DNS: Local domain, which Windows' `WorkGroup` name must match; all other OSes allow specifying a `LocalDomain`)_ - e.g. access LuCI via `https://openwrt.lan` instead of its IP, or a NAS via `https://<NetworkHostname>.lan`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The way to associate a MAC address with a description is to use a Lua program and associate the code with a LuCI page, which I didn't do:

```lua
function dump(o)
  if type(o) == 'table' then
    local s = '{ '.. string.char(10)
    for k, v in pairs(o) do
      if type(k) ~= 'number' then
        k = '"' .. k .. '"'
      end
      s = s .. '[' .. k .. '] = ' .. dump(v) .. string.char(10)
    end
    return s .. '} '.. string.char(10)
  else
    return tostring(o)
  end
end

HostData = {}
function HostData.new(macAddr, description)
  return { MacAddress = macAddr, Description = description }
end

Dictionary = {}
hostdata = HostData.new("12:34:56:78", "My first Powerful Laptop")
Dictionary[1] = hostdata
hostdata = HostData.new("78:34:56:12", "My SuperDuper laptop")
Dictionary[2] = hostdata
print("dictionary: ", dump(Dictionary))
```

- A better version of this can probably pull up IP addresses and hostnames from the DHCP server, adding them to the above data

Comment: Why would this be necessary/needed over the normal way of doing so by configuring a static IP for the MAC entry, which is set either via LuCI's _Network_ → _DHCP and DNS_ → _Static Leases_ or via [`/etc/config/dhcp`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp) _(see [Static leases](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp#static_leases))_? Within hostnames, whitespaces and symbols cannot be used, but hyphens can be.

Comment: There are devices where you can't set names, such as IoT devices, eg weighing machine, certain TVs, certain phones, certain family appliances, etc. All these devices have random hostnames making it difficult or challenging to identify what it is. With a description, it allows one to easily and quickly identify it, without performing mental gymnastics trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: As stated in the comment under your question: "_There appears to be a confusion between hostname set on a client device and hostnames set on a router... On router OSes, hostname is set by configuring a static IP for the MAC entry_". That is the standard way of doing what you're looking for. Configuring static entries for clients on a router also makes accessing them way simpler since their `<hostname>.<localdomain>` can be used instead of their IP _(`LocalDomain` is set on the router, which Windows' WorkGroup name must match)_- e.g. access LuCI via `https://openwrt.lan` instead of it's IP

Comment: This isn't a real answer. This code does nothing but print hardcoded values. There's a lot of work that needs to be done to create a LuCI module (far more than copying a dump function off SE and writing 10 extra lines of pointless code). And this question doesn't even link to resources on actually building a module. Even if that was done, it would have *no* effect on the entire rest of the LuCI interface. "pull up IP addresses and hostnames from the DHCP server" is also a lot more work than w/e this is. You have not achieved your goal, and nobody will be able to achieve it with this answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to assign a hostname to a DHCP client based on its mac address then you can configure that in `/etc/config/dhcp` with a block like this:

```
config host
    option name myhost
    option mac de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe
```

You can also add an `option ip` to reserve a specific IP address for it.

You can either edit the file, use the `uci` command-line tool or do it through the LuCI web application. Remember to `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart` after changing the config file with an editor or `uci commit` if using `uci`.

I realise that `jim's device` is probably not a host name but assigning a host name (e.g `jim_device`) will at least make devices recognisable by a name of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a static lease is the easiest way I have found to associate a name with a MAC address through the LuCI web interface, as of OpenWRT 22.03. Note that you don't actually have to assign a static IP, this feature defines the DHCP lease settings to use for that device, which may include dynamic IP if you don't assign a static one. Either way, the name is added to the local DNS, so other machines on the LAN can use that assigned name if they are using the router for DNS.

The hostnames feature of the UI does not allow you to specify the MAC address.

Comment: In order to set a hostname for a client device on a router, the MAC address _must_ be specified - LuCI: _Network_ → _Hostnames_ is not for this. Configuring a static IP for a MAC entry is set either via LuCI's _Network_ → _DHCP and DNS_ → _Static Leases_ or via [`/etc/config/dhcp`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp) _(see [Static leases](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp#static_leases))_.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. I have used this many times and it works. I tried rewording some sentences that were confusing in retrospect.

Comment: Oh I see, the user retroactively changed his question. Yeah, I'm not aware of a way to assign a name that is displayed in the OpenWRT UI but not published by DNS. If you don't need local DNS, then you could assign a static lease and disable DNS, which would create an alias without exposing it to the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do solely on the LuCI interface.
Network -> DHCP and DNS -> Static Leases -> Add

At time of writing, the "form" looks like this:
[image]
You can specify hostname, MAC address, and leave IPv4 address *unspecified*. The same lines will be added to `/etc/config/dhcp` as if you had followed [starfry's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1272453/635128) and done it manually.

Comment: You did read that I say it's not a hostname right? The solution you're giving is a hostname.

Comment: @chuacw My answer merely complements starfry's answer. As I said, it does the exact same thing he's doing to `/etc/config/dhcp` but through the LuCI interface. You didn't complain about his answer, so why are you complaining about mine? You're also asking for something that's not possible, seen as there hasn't been an accepted answer for 7 years - my answer will at least help people (like me) who stumble upon your question, looking to give hostnames to devices that just plain don't have them to begin with - or those who don't have your self-imposed limitations.

Comment: starfry's answer was given when I forgot to specify that hostname is not the answer.
After he answered, I realized nobody knew I'm not asking about hostname, so I specified the "not/no hostname" requirement. 

Yet, after specifying the answer should not be a hostname, everyone still answers hostname.

The proper answer should be: https://superuser.com/a/1836802/129113 as I specified.

Comment: @chuacw maybe post a different question instead of editing your old one (**with already perfectly-acceptable answers**) to have new requirements. And whose title remains unchanged and doesn't in any way reflect the new requirements you decided to add in, **after being provided with perfectly-acceptable answers**.

Comment: @chuacw starfry deserved to have his answer accepted **as per your own initial requirements** - instead you edited your question, and later downvoted my own answer when I expanded on that initial answer. So maybe don't then post something **non-functional** and mark it as the answer *out of spite* just because I said there was no answer to your edited-in requirements. 7 years later you're being this petty, and you **still** have no answer to your question.

Comment: @TrisT Yours and starfry's answer are the correct answers to the OP's question - yours is GUI, starfry's is CLI. The OP has a _fundamental_ misunderstanding of terminology - please see my comments under the OP's question.